# How to check for operator != existence for template arguments with C++ 17?

Tags: c++, templates, operators, c++17

I have the following use case:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
  bool setValue(T const &iValue)
  {
    if(fValue != iValue)
    {
      fValue = iValue;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  T fValue;
};
```

which works only as long as `T` provides a `operator!=` implementation (and I suppose one of the complication is that `operator!=` can be implemented as member function of `T` or not...).

Ideally I would like to write something like this using C++ 17 `if constexpr` syntax

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
  bool setValue(T const &iValue)
  {
    if constexpr (is_diff_operator_defined<T>::value) {
      if(fValue != iValue)
      {
        fValue = iValue;
        return true;
      }
    } else {
        fValue = iValue;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  T fValue;
};
```

How would I go about it? Please note I am using C++ 17 so would prefer a solution that uses the latest and greatest feature (likes `if constexpr` which makes the code a lot easier to read/comprehend than optional dummy template function parameters we usually see with sfinae...)

Comment: Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected for inspiration, it's an idiom for this that is a level of abstraction higher than writing a specific trait to check for the operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the detection idiom it's quite simple to do:

```
template<typename T>
using operator_not_eq_t = decltype(std::declval<T const&>() != std::declval<T const&>());

template<typename T>
constexpr auto is_diff_operator_defined = is_detected_v<operator_not_eq_t, T>;
```

Then simply use it with `if constexpr` as you wrote. (minus `::value`)

Note that with concepts you can simply do that inline:

```
if constexpr (requires { fValue != iValue; }) {
    if (fValue != iValue) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This indeed works, but I just want to point out that `is_detected_v` is currently defined in `<experimental/type_traits>` which does *not* work with Visual Studio Build tools 2017. It does work with XCode 9.2. So to be cross platform I had to copy/adapt the code from XCode into my source code so that it works on both platforms.

Comment: @yan the detection idiom can certainly work on visual studio, 2019, 2017 and 2015, and maybe even older. To do that you can simply implement `is_detected` in a few lines and confidently use it everywhere.

Comment: That is exactly what I said in my comment: "I had to copy/adapt the code from XCode into my source code so that it works on both platforms". Thanks for pointing out that you can also port it in older versions.